# Persist an entity in a ManyToOne relationship without creating a new linked entity

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4, symfony-4.2

I have a concern with the persistence of my entities for a ManyToOne Unidirectionnal relationship. In fact I have an entity **Order** linked to a **ticket** entity, in the order form I have a choices to select the ticket. 
This is foreign key in Command Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CommandRepository")
 */
class Command
    {
….       
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Ticket")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="Ticket_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $ticket;

...
```

the Builder of CommandForm is

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('datevisite', DateType::class,['widget' => 'choice',
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'html5' => false,'label'=>'Date de la visite', 'attr'=>['class' => 'js-datepicker'] ])
            ->add('ticket', EntityType::class,['required'=>true, 'class' => Ticket::class,'choice_label'=>'nombillet', 'attr'=>['placeholder'=>'Choisissez le type de billet']])
                  ->add('email', EmailType::class,['required'=>true, 'label'=>'Votre mail', 'attr'=>['placeholder'=>'Entrez votre adresse mail ']])
            ;
```

When I save (persist) an Command with

```
$manager->persist($command);
 $manager->flush();
```

instead of registering the command with the selected ticket  in the drop-down list, a new ticket is automatically created and assigned to the command.

please help me to persist only the Command with the foreign key of existing ticket (selected)
Thanks

Comment: Show the code of your controller, pls

Answer (score 0):

my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Command;
use App\Notification\NotificationContact;
use App\Entity\Typebillet;
use App\Entity\Typetarif;
use App\Entity\Visiteur;
use App\Form\Type\CommandType;
use App\Module\Module;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;

class LouvreController extends AbstractController
{

   private $lacommand ;
   private $session;

   public function __construct()
    {

           $this->lacommand = new Command();


    }

 /**
     * @Route("/billet/reservation", name="louvre_billet")
     */
    public function billet(Request $request,  SessionInterface $session){

          //  $this->lacommand = new command();

            //$form = $this->createFormBuilder($command)
            $form = $this->createForm(CommandType::class, $this->lacommand);
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                  $this->lacommand->setDatecommande(new \DateTime());

                   $today = new \DateTime();
                   if  ( Module::CommandeJourPasse($this->lacommand->getDatevisite()) == -1 ) {
                        return $this->rediriger('danger', 'Attention vous ne pouvez commander un billet pour un jour passé!!!', 'louvre_billet');

                    }

                   if  ( Module::AuDela14H($this->lacommand->getTypebillet()->getId(), $this->lacommand->getDatevisite() ) == -1 ) {
                        return $this->rediriger('danger', 'Attention vous ne pouvez commander un billet journée au delà de 14 le jour même', 'louvre_billet');

                    }
  if ( $this->recherchetarif($this->lacommand) === -1) {

                        $this->addFlash('danger', 'Attention vous devez enregistrer au moins un visiteur ' );               
                          return $this->redirectToRoute('louvre_billet', array(), 301);
                                    }
                                       $nbrebilletDuJourDeVisite =  $this->getDoctrine()
                                    ->getRepository(Command::class)
                                    ->sumNumberVisite( $this->lacommand->getDatevisite()->format('Y-m-d')  );

                                 if (($nbrebilletDuJourDeVisite + $this->lacommand->getNombrebillet()) > 1000) {
                             $dispo = 1000 - $nbrebilletDuJourDeVisite;
                            $this->addFlash('danger', 'Attention votre commande ne peut être effectuée, car la capacité d\' accueil journalière est limitée à 1000 visites. Actuellemnt '.$dispo.' billet(s) disponible(s)' );               
                          return $this->redirectToRoute('louvre_billet', array(), 301);
                                    }

              $verif = $this->verifJourOuvrables($this->lacommand->getDatevisite());
                       if($verif['error'] >0) {

                            $this->addFlash('danger', $verif['message'] );               
                          return $this->redirectToRoute('louvre_billet', array(), 301);
                                    }


                    $session->set('command', $this->lacommand);
                    return $this->paie($this->lacommand);

            }


                              return $this->render('louvre/resa.html.twig', array(
                            'formCommand' => $form->createView(),
                        ));


    }


     public function paie(Command $command){

        return $this->render('louvre/paiement.html.twig',   [
                        'datevisite'=> $command->getDatevisite()->format('d-M-Y'),
                        'nombrebillet' => $command->getNombrebillet(),
                        'montantnet' => $command->getMontantnet(),
                        'email' => $command->getEmail() ,
                        'command'=>$command] );



     }

     /**
     * @Route("/billet/paiement", name="le_paiement")
     */
    public function paiement( Request $request,  ObjectManager $manager, SessionInterface $session , \Swift_Mailer $mailer){



                if ($request->request->get('stripeToken') !== null) {

                       $command = $session->get('command');
                   /* dump($command);
                    die();*/
                       $montantnetCent =  $command->getMontantnet() * 100;

                    try{

                    // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
                    // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys 
                    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_0thjJ32tl0y6X8kc5Wdz0XSt");


                    // Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
                    // Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
                    $token = $request->request->get('stripeToken');
                    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
                        'amount' =>  $montantnetCent,
                        'currency' => 'eur',
                        'description' => 'Achat billet musée de Louvre  -- '.$command->getEmail(),
                        'source' => $token,
                    ]);

                     }

                      catch (Exception $e) {

                        $error = $e->getMessage();
                        $this->addFlash('danger', $error );               
                          return $this->redirectToRoute('louvre_billet', array(), 301); 
                      } 

                      /** 
                       * ici on va générer et insérer le code 
                       */
                      $code = $command->getDatevisite()->format('ymd')."-".substr($command->getTypebillet()->getNombillet(),0,4)."-".uniqid();
                      $command->setCode($code);

                      $manager->persist($command);


                      $manager->flush($command);
                    /**
                     * envoie de mail
                     */

                    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Musée de LOUVRE : Votre reservation '))
                ->setFrom('louvre@museelouvre.com')
                ->setTo($command->getEmail())
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                        // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
                        'emails/mail.html.twig',
                        array('datevisite' => $command->getDatevisite(),
                                'typebillet' => $command->getTypebillet()->getNombillet(),
                                'montantnet' => $command->getMontantnet(),
                                'visiteurs' => $command->getVisiteurs(),
                                'code'     => $command-> getCode(),
                        )
                    ),
                    'text/html'
                );

                $mailer->send($message);
dump($mailer->send($message));

                        /**
                         * fin envoie
                         */

                         return $this->render(
                        // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
                        'emails/mail.html.twig',
                        array('datevisite' => $command->getDatevisite(),
                                'typebillet' => $command->getTypebillet()->getNombillet(),
                                'montantnet' => $command->getMontantnet(),
                                'visiteurs' => $command->getVisiteurs(),
                                'code' => $command->getCode()

                        ));

                    /*$this->addFlash('success', 'Paiement effectué avec succes ' );               
                          return $this->redirectToRoute('louvre_billet', array(), 301); */




                }
                else{

                         $this->addFlash('danger', 'Un probleme est survenu lors du paiement ' );               
                          return $this->redirectToRoute('louvre_billet', array(), 301);
                }



    }

     public function recherchetarif(Command $command){

                      $tarif = new Typetarif();
                    $today = new \DateTime();
                    $reduction = 0;
                    $montantbrut = 0;
                    $lesvisiteurs= new ArrayCollection();
                   $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


                if ($command->getVisiteurs()->count() == 0) {
                    return -1;
                }

                  foreach ($command->getVisiteurs() as $visiteur) {

                      # code...
                    /**
                     * On calcule l'age de chaque visiteur et on recupère le tarif correspondant
                     */
                     $datenais = $visiteur->getDatenaissance()->format('Y-m-d');
                     $datenais = new \DateTime($datenais);
                     $age = date_diff($today, $datenais);



                    $tarif =  $this->getDoctrine()
                                    ->getRepository(Typetarif::class)
                                    ->findCostByAge($age->y);



                    // $command->removeVisiteur($visiteur);
                    $visiteur->setTypetarif($tarif);

                    $montantbrut = $montantbrut + $tarif->getTarifmontant();

                    $lesvisiteurs->add($visiteur);

                   //$manager->persist($visiteur->getTypetarif());
                  }


                // on calcul le montant brut de la facture brut = PUBillet x Nbre de billet
                    //$montantbrut = $tarif->getTarifmontant() * $command->getNombrebillet();
                    $command->setMontantbrut ($montantbrut);
                    $command->setNombrebillet($command->getVisiteurs()->count());
                // On impute une éventuelle reduction de 10 euros
                    if ( $command->getTarifreduit()==true) {
                        $reduction = 10;
                    } 
                        $command->setMontantreduit($reduction);

                // on applique le montant net  = montant brut - reduction

                    $command->setMontantnet($montantbrut - $reduction);



            return 0;


     }


     public function verifJourOuvrables($datevisite)
     {  $error = 0;
        $message = '';

        if ($datevisite->format('N') == 2) {
            $error = $error + 1;
            $message = 'Désolé le musée n\' pas oiuvert le Mardi !!!';
            return ['error'=>$error, 'message'=>$message];
        }

        if ($datevisite->format('j') == 1 and $datevisite->format('m')==5) {
            $error = $error + 1;
            $message = 'Désolé le musée n\' ouvre pas le 1er MAI !!!';
            return ['error'=>$error, 'message'=>$message];
        }

         if ($datevisite->format('j') == 1 and $datevisite->format('m')==11) {
            $error = $error + 1;
            $message = 'Désolé le musée n\' ouvre pas le 1er Novembre !!!';
            return ['error'=>$error, 'message'=>$message];
        }

         if ($datevisite->format('j') == 25 and $datevisite->format('m')==12) {
            $error = $error + 1;
            $message = 'Désolé le musée n\' ouvre pas le 25 Decembre !!!';
            return ['error'=>$error, 'message'=>$message];

        }

     }

  public   function rediriger($type, $message, $route){
        $this->addFlash($type , $message );
        return $this->redirectToRoute($route, array(), 301);
     }



}
```

In this Controller, the function use to persist all the Entities is

```
/**
     * @Route("/billet/paiement", name="le_paiement")
     */
    public function paiement( Request $request,  ObjectManager $manager, SessionInterface $session , \Swift_Mailer $mailer){



                if ($request->request->get('stripeToken') !== null) {

                       $command = $session->get('command');
                   /* dump($command);
                    die();*/
                       $montantnetCent =  $command->getMontantnet() * 100;

                    try{

                    // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
                    // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys 
                    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_0thjJ32tl0y6X8kc5Wdz0XSt");


                    // Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
                    // Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
                    $token = $request->request->get('stripeToken');
                    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
                        'amount' =>  $montantnetCent,
                        'currency' => 'eur',
                        'description' => 'Achat billet musée de Louvre  -- '.$command->getEmail(),
                        'source' => $token,
                    ]);

                     }

                      catch (Exception $e) {

                        $error = $e->getMessage();
                        $this->addFlash('danger', $error );               
                          return $this->redirectToRoute('louvre_billet', array(), 301); 
                      } 

                      /** 
                       * ici on va générer et insérer le code 
                       */
                      $code = $command->getDatevisite()->format('ymd')."-".substr($command->getTypebillet()->getNombillet(),0,4)."-".uniqid();
                      $command->setCode($code);

                      $manager->persist($command);


                      $manager->flush($command);
                    /**
                     * envoie de mail
                     */

                    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Musée de LOUVRE : Votre reservation '))
                ->setFrom('louvre@museelouvre.com')
                ->setTo($command->getEmail())
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                        // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
                        'emails/mail.html.twig',
                        array('datevisite' => $command->getDatevisite(),
                                'typebillet' => $command->getTypebillet()->getNombillet(),
                                'montantnet' => $command->getMontantnet(),
                                'visiteurs' => $command->getVisiteurs(),
                                'code'     => $command-> getCode(),
                        )
                    ),
                    'text/html'
                );

                $mailer->send($message);
dump($mailer->send($message));

                        /**
                         * fin envoie
                         */

                         return $this->render(
                        // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
                        'emails/mail.html.twig',
                        array('datevisite' => $command->getDatevisite(),
                                'typebillet' => $command->getTypebillet()->getNombillet(),
                                'montantnet' => $command->getMontantnet(),
                                'visiteurs' => $command->getVisiteurs(),
                                'code' => $command->getCode()

                        ));

                    /*$this->addFlash('success', 'Paiement effectué avec succes ' );               
                          return $this->redirectToRoute('louvre_billet', array(), 301); */




                }
                else{

                         $this->addFlash('danger', 'Un probleme est survenu lors du paiement ' );               
                          return $this->redirectToRoute('louvre_billet', array(), 301);
                }



    }
```

Thanks